# Looping through byte array - java

Tags: java

I would like to try and loop through this following byte array:

```
public byte[] mFFTBytes;
```

How would I go about doing this in java with a for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how do you fetch the value of mFFTBytes. It's no wonder that you get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to instantiate your array because you will have null pointer exceptions all over the place.

Then you can use a for each loop

```
for(byte b : mFFTBytes){
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: I am now getting an error on the for(byte b : mFFTBytes){ line - it is a nullpointerexception - do you know what could be causing this

Comment: That's because you didn't initialize mFFTBytes. You need to do :
`public byte[] mFFTBytes = new byte[size];`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand well what you are asking for. Going through any array in Java is quite trivial action like:

```
        for (byte myByte: mFFTBytes) {
            //do something with myByte
        }
```

or

```
        for (int i=0;i<mFFTBytes.length;i++) {
            //do something with mFFTBytes[i]
        }
```

The latter should be faster, but for a vast majority of applications is does not matter much.